# Why does it say constructor dog in class dog cannot be applied to given types? It seems to run but throws an error, why is that?

Tags: java, class, error-handling, constructor

[**code draft**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhiQh.png)

Does it have to do with the Strings or the phrasing of the parameters? I really don't know what else it could be when it throws this error.

Comment: Please do not post pictures like this. The StackOverflow question can have Code Snippets embedded, which makes it easier for people to answer you.

Comment: To which types can the constructor not be applied? Please post the exact and complete error message you get and the code that causes (i.e. the code that tries to invoke the constructor). In fact, please post [a complete runnable code sample that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your second constructor should be like this:

```
public void Dog (String theName, int theAge) {
    name = theName;
    age = theAge;
}
```

Constructors need to have the same name as that of the object it builds.  Your error is because the program is trying to call the top constructor with only 2 arguments (I'm assuming a bit here, as you did not provide the code that causes the error).

Another small tip, you could try structuring your constructors like this to make it a bit cleaner:

```
public Dog (String name, int age, int weight) {
    this.super(name, age);
    this.weight = weight;
}

public Dog (String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Hope that helps.  Posting more code will be helpful if you have further problems.